# Problema al usar inner join en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Al realizar una consulta en MySQL por medio de:

```
select * from citas where fecha > '2020-09-02';
```

Ésta me regresa los datos que están almacenados, pero al realizar la misma consulta de esta otra forma:

```
select veterinaria.mascota.Nombre_Paciente, 
       veterinaria.cliente.Nombre_Cliente, 
       veterinaria.cliente.Primer_Apellido, 
       veterinaria.cliente.Segundo_Apellido,
       veterinaria.cliente.Correo_Electronico, 
       veterinaria.citas.Fecha, 
       veterinaria.citas.HoraInicio 
from veterinaria.mascota
     inner join veterinaria.cliente on veterinaria.mascota.IdMascota = veterinaria.cliente.IdCliente
     inner join veterinaria.citas on veterinaria.cliente.IdCliente = veterinaria.mascota.IdMascota
where Fecha > '2020-09-02';
```

No me muestra ninguno de los datos almacenados. ¿Por qué puede ocurrir eso? ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hiciste un where "Fecha" ... pero no le has dicho que Fecha usar. No sería más lógico... `WHERE veterinaria.cita.Fecha` ???

Answer (score 0):

No conozco la estructura de tus tablas pero veo que  no estas utilizando campos de la tabla `citas` en la condición del join para relacionarla con las otras tablas.

Hice unas tablas de ejemplo:

Tabla cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla citas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si nos damos cuenta ambas tablas tienen un campo en común (`id_cliente`) que nos servirá para relacionarlas mediante el join.
El join de mi ejemplo quedaría de la siguente forma:

```
 select a.id_cliente,
   a.nombre,       
   b.id_cita,
   b.fecha     
 from cliente a
 inner join citas b on a.id_cliente = b.id_cliente
 where b.fecha > '2020-09-02';
```

Y basado en mis datos el resultado sería el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya logre resolver ese temana tenia los join colocados de forma erronea, ahora mi problema es que al hacer un procedimiento almacenado no me muestra las fechas